# Symmetric operators and their extensions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let us consider self-adjoint, positive operator $M$. Assume that operator $M$ is extension for the operator $C^2$, where operator $C$ is simple maximal symmetric.  Is there a possibility to characterize dependence between operator $M$ and $C$? Is also $M$ extension for operator $C$?

Comment: Does $C^2$ mean the square of $C$? If so why would you expect $M$ to be an extension for operator $C$?

Comment: $C^2$ means the square of $C$.

Comment: If $M$ is an extension for the operator $C^2$ then by definition it agrees with $C^2$ on the domain of $C^2$. Can it also  agree with $C$ on the domain of $C$ ?